# Problem 3-35(a) in "Calculus on Manifolds" by Michael Spivak. If I show $\chi_{g(U)}:C\to\mathbb{R}$ is integrable, then is my proof ok?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, fubini-tonelli-theorems

> Problem 3-35
> (a) Let $g:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ be a linear transformation of one of the following types:
> $$\begin{cases}
> g(e_i)=e_i & i\neq j \\
> g(e_j)=ae_j &
> \end{cases}$$
> $$\begin{cases}
> g(e_i)=e_i & i\neq j \\
> g(e_j)=e_j+e_k &
> \end{cases}$$
> $$\begin{cases}
> g(e_k)=e_k & k\neq i,j\\
> g(e_i)=e_j &\\
> g(e_j)=e_i &
> \end{cases}$$
> If $U$ is a rectangle, show that the volume of $g(U)$ is $|\det g|\cdot v(U)$.

When $g$ is a linear transformation such that $$\begin{cases}
g(e_i)=e_i & i\neq j \\
g(e_j)=e_j+e_k &
,\end{cases}$$ I tried to show $v(g(U))=|\det g|\cdot v(U)$.

Let $U=[a_1,b_1]\times\cdots\times [a_n,b_n]$.
Then, $g(U)=\{(x_1,\dots,x_n):x_i\in [a_i,b_i] \left(i\in\{1,\dots,n\}-\{k\}\right),x_j+a_k\leq x_k\leq x_j+b_k\}$.
Let $C=[a_1,b_1]\times\cdots\times [a_{k-1},b_{k-1}]\times [a_j+a_k,b_j+b_k]\times [a_{k+1},b_{k+1}]\times\cdots\times [a_n,b_n]$.
Let $A=[a_1,b_1]\times\cdots\times [a_{k-1},b_{k-1}]\times [a_{k+1},b_{k+1}]\times\cdots\times [a_n,b_n]$.
Let $B=[a_j+a_k,b_j+b_k]$.
I need to show $\chi_{g(U)}:C\to\mathbb{R}$ is integrable to use Fubini's theorem.
But I haven't shown this fact yet.
I will use this fact without a proof.
By Fubini's theorem, $$v(g(U))=\int_C \chi_{g(U)}=\int_A\left(\int_B \chi_{g(U)}\right)=\int_{(x_1,\dots,x_{k-1},x_{k+1},\dots,x_n)\in A}\left(\int_{a_j+a_k}^{b_j+b_k} \chi_{g(U)}(x_1,\dots,x_{k-1},t_k,x_{k+1},\dots,x_n)dt_k\right)=\int_{(x_1,\dots,x_{k-1},x_{k+1},\dots,x_n)\in A}\left(\int_{x_j+a_k}^{x_j+b_k} 1dt_k\right)=\int_{(x_1,\dots,x_{k-1},x_{k+1},\dots,x_n)\in A} (b_k-a_k)=(b_k-a_k)\cdot\int_{(x_1,\dots,x_{k-1},x_{k+1},\dots,x_n)\in A} 1=v(U).$$

Obviously $\det g=1$.

So, $v(g(U))=|\det g|\cdot v(U)$.

If I show $\chi_{g(U)}:C\to\mathbb{R}$ is integrable, then is my proof ok?

In particular, I am unsure whether the following equation is correct.
$g(U)=\{(x_1,\dots,x_n):x_i\in [a_i,b_i] \left(i\in\{1,\dots,n\}-\{k\}\right),x_j+a_k\leq x_k\leq x_j+b_k\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function looks correct. $\chi_{g_{U}}$ is integrable because the boundary of a closed rectangle always has measure $0$, as the boundary is, casually speaking, $n-1$ dimensional while we are in an $n$-dimensional space, so the rectangle is Jordan-measurable, and $\chi_{g_{U}}$ is integrable.

Comment: ccream, thank you very much for your answer.